# Can we say that a thread is a process?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

Can we say that any individual thread **(which is defined as an instance of a process)** is a process itself?

Comment: Saying that a thread is a process is a misuse of language. Threads and processes are two fundamentally different entities (with different properties). A thread is always attached to one process (its parent) and cannot exist alone. A thread alone in a process is still a thread and not a process. Note that some people consider processes as "heavy-processes" and threads as "lightweight-processes" (which is still fine because there is a distinction despite being a bit confusing).

Comment: Oh thankyou very much, I was confused due to the heavy-weight and lightweight concept. It's clear now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we say that any individual thread (which is defined as an instance of a process) is a process itself?

No. Threads and processes are fundamentally different things. A "thread" is a context of execution which takes a sequence of computational steps. A "process" is a container that typically consists of things like a view of memory, file descriptors, and so on and can contain one or more threads.

These concepts sometimes get confused because many systems in the past had a one-to-one correspondence between threads and processes, that is, each process had exactly one thread. As a result, they called the thing that got scheduled for execution a "process".

Later, when support for processes with more than one thread was added, that meant creating more than one thing that gets scheduled for execution, and those were called "processes". This has mostly been cleaned up, but you will still seem systems, code, and papers from that era that do not quite align with modern usage because of these kinds of transitions.